# execute callback even if jquery statement fails

Tags: jquery, callback, execution

I have a jquery statement as follows:

```
$('.panel.col2, .panel.col3').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    //SOME CODE
});
```

The problem is that these elements do not always exist, and I need it to execute the callback regardless of the success of the statement the callback belongs to. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Sounds like it is not really a callback then?

Comment: the point is that it needs to be executed always AFTER the elements are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function myCallback(){
   //SOME CODE
}

if($('.panel.col2, .panel.col3').length>0){

   $('.panel.col2, .panel.col3').fadeOut('fast', function(){
       myCallback();
   });
} else {
   myCallback();
}
```

Comment: This is a bit more organized. That is why I chose it as the anaswer.

Comment: @sightofnick ... this is actually less efficient as using the same jQuery selector multiple times in the same code block causes additional looping.  It would be more efficient to simply store the jQuery object in a variable and then use the variable.  Example:  var mypanelelement = $('.panel.col2, .panel.col3');  Now you can use the variable mypanelelement instead of forcing jQuery to search for the element again.

Comment: @John Hartsock: Of course you're right but I spotted weakness in your code too - you define function only when the document is loaded and this code could be loaded much earlier. Depends on complecity of code inside a function of course. Anyway it is kick in the performance. P.S. Yes, I should wrap everything else in document ready then. I know :).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want some code to run in the call back for `fadeOut` and outside if their are no elements to fade out.  Here is an idea but I do not know the context of what you are trying to do.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  var panelElement = $('.panel.col2, .panel.col3');
  var fadeOutCallBack = function(){
    //SOME CODE
  };
  panelElement.fadeOut('fast', fadeOutCallBack);
  if (panelElement.length == 0) {
    fadeOutCallBack();
  }
});
```